Handling Authentication in Next.js App with NextAuth from Chrome Extension
I'm working with two different applications:
A Next.js app with NextAuth for authentication.
A Chrome extension that interacts with this Next.js app.
Goal: I need to manage authentication from the Chrome extension so it can fetch data from the Next.js API.
What I Tried
To retrieve the session within the Chrome extension, I'm using:
fetch("https://localhost:3000/api/auth/session")

This works fine for session retrieval. However, when I try to fetch user tokens with the following code:
const response = await fetch(
      "http://localhost:3000/api/user/tokens",
      {
        method: "GET",
        credentials: "include",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
);

I get a 401 Unauthorized error. Here’s the API endpoint in my Next.js app:
// GET endpoint to retrieve user's tokens
export async function GET() {
    try {
        const session = (await getServerSession(authOptions)) as Session & {
            user?: {
                id: string;
            };
        };

        if (!session?.user?.id) {
            return NextResponse.json({ error: "Unauthorized" }, { status: 401 });
        }

        await connectMongo();
        const user = await User.findById(session.user.id).select('tokens');

        if (!user) {
            return NextResponse.json({ error: "User not found" }, { status: 404 });
        }

        return NextResponse.json({ tokens: user.tokens });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching tokens:", error);
        return NextResponse.json(
            { error: "Internal server error" },
            { status: 500 }
        );
    }
}

I'm getting a 401 Unauthorized response when calling the /api/user/tokens endpoint. I believe it’s due to authentication issues from the Chrome extension, even though I'm including { credentials: "include" } in the fetch request.
Questions
How can I correctly authenticate requests from my Chrome extension? Is there a specific setup for NextAuth to work with Chrome extensions?
Is there a better way to securely access authenticated endpoints from a Chrome extension in a Next.js/NextAuth setup?
Any help or insights would be appreciated! Thank you.
